# Tkinter button bind issues

Tags: python, button, tkinter

My goal is to eventually have a few labels and entries that appear and correspond with the different days of the week. I am currently working on getting the button binding to generate a different label depending on which day of the week is selected. It's sort of working, but not how I expected and not how I really want. Right now I have to click on a button twice for it to update the label. I'm still pretty new to programming and I appreciate any help you can provide!

```
root = Tk()
root.geometry('300x300')
root.title('Day')

frame3 = Frame(root)
frame4 = Frame(root)
frame3.grid()

dayFrame = Frame(frame4)
class App(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.var1 = StringVar()
        self.var1.set('')
        self.sunBtn = Button(frame3, text='Sunday', command=lambda day='Sunday': self.var1.set(day))
        self.sunBtn.bind('<Button-1>', self.openFrame)
        self.sunBtn.grid(row=1, column=0)
        self.monBtn = Button(frame3, text='Monday', command=lambda day='Monday': self.var1.set(day))
        self.monBtn.bind('<Button-1>', self.openFrame)
        self.monBtn.grid(row=1, column=1)

    def openFrame(self,*args):
        frame4.grid()
        dayFrame.grid()
        dayLbl = Label(dayFrame, text=self.var1.get())
        dayLbl.grid(row=1, column=0)

app = App(root)
app.mainloop()
```

UPDATE: I realized my mistake. I feel dumb. I replaced

```
self.var1.set('')
```

with

```
self.var1.trace('w', self.openFrame)
```

and it seems like everything is working properly. Hopefully this can help another beginner at some point!

Comment: Please don't use edits to write an answer in the question. If you feel you have found the answer yourself, you can post an answer to your own question. This keeps answers separated from questions. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use bind and command at the same time:
(and don't forget to write your import line)

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry('300x300')
root.title('Day')

frame3 = Frame(root)
frame4 = Frame(root)
frame3.grid()

dayFrame = Frame(frame4)
class App(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.var1 = StringVar()
        self.var1.set('')
        self.sunBtn = Button(frame3, text='Sunday', command= lambda: self.openFrame('Sunday'))
        self.sunBtn.grid(row=1, column=0)
        self.monBtn = Button(frame3, text='Monday', command=lambda: self.openFrame('Monday'))
        self.monBtn.grid(row=1, column=1)

    def openFrame(self, day):
        frame4.grid()
        dayFrame.grid()
        dayLbl = Label(dayFrame, text=day)
        dayLbl.grid(row=1, column=0)

app = App(root)
app.mainloop()
```

A very different (and probably better) solution:

```
from tkinter import *
import calendar

root = Tk()
root.geometry('600x300')
root.title('Day')

frame3 = Frame(root)
frame4 = Frame(root)
frame3.grid()

dayFrame = Frame(frame4)
class App(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)        
        frame4.grid()
        dayFrame.grid()
        self.dayLbl = Label(dayFrame, text="")
        self.dayLbl.grid(row=1, column=0)
        for i,  day in enumerate(calendar.day_name):
            button = Button(frame3, text=day, command= lambda day=day:\
                self.dayLbl.configure(text=day))
            button.grid(row=1, column=i)         

app = App(root)
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: If someone can tell me if I should write two answers, delete the first one or....